# Could someone the real IP address when using tunnel protocols like ngrok, localtunnel or serveo?

Tags: network, protocols, tunneling

Could someone get the real IP address that is hidden behind the URL generated by tools like ngrok, localtunnel or serveo?

Comment: Define safe. The encryption used in popular tunneling protocols such as OpenVPN and IPSec is sound.

Comment: Safe as in like the other people can not find the local IP from the generated url, which is used by tools like `ngrok`, `localtunnel`, `serveo` etc @vidarlo

Comment: @thecowmilk: I've narrowed down your question to specific tools and only getting the IP address. Covering every kind of tunnels and asking about the very broad meaning of "safe" would make the question too broad. Specifically these tools usually don't protect your internal server against any kind of application level attacks like SQL injection, command injection or similar.

Comment: @Steffen_Ullrich i dont really care about sql injections attacks as I just host some files for my mates on a project we are making, I care much more about the IP. Not that my mates would try to harm me but just a security thought when i will use these kind of tools again for other projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say "No, they cannot", but that depends on the application on your side. Those applications won't show anything on your side, but what you are tunneling is your responsibility.

If your application does not leak the IP in any header, error message, content or anything, your internal IP is protected. Just make sure your application don't have any error message saying `Apache 2.4.46 at 10.20.30.40`.